# Save/Export image from compositing tab in Blender 2.81

Tags: export, compositing-nodes

[image]Any way to save the pre-rendered picture as JPG/PNG from the compositor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to connect the *Viewer Node*.
Then just open your *Image Editor*, select *Viewer Node* and save the image.

You can save to any format you need *.jpg/.EXR* are all supported.

[image]

Note:
If the *Viewer node* doesn't show any image, just toggle one of your nodes off/on.
*Viewer/Composite* nodes refresh *only* when there's a change in the compositor.

[image]

Comment: @Jachym wow, that worked, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :). I had to figure it out because I often edit external .exr files.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to interpret your question.

If you mean save out your render before the composite; go to your compositor then 'shift+a > output > file output' and connect it directly to your render output node.

If you mean that you rendered the image and are compositing using the live view after: There isn't an instant way of doing that presently. You can maximize the node editor using ctrl+space and do a screenshot or re render the frame. If its just for a preview image that you want to save you can turn down your resolution or ray count (be sure to have denoise in your composite node tree if you do that) to make it faster if time is an issue. The back image in the compositor is just a preview, it is not meant to be a final render product.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy, I should've been more precise, my situation is closer to the second option. That's sad, I have a highres EXR file in my compositor and the only thing I want to change is the background color.

Answer (score -1):

The way I save any scene is to use the print screen button on the keyboard. Click it then  open up a picture editor like Microsoft paint because it loads fast, and paste, crop picture if you want, and then click save as. For more options on editing the picture use a program like Gimp to past the picture into.